# Client Error Youtube API python

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a python program which query youtube to get the video details. I use the version-3 api. I have multiple processes **m** and a python pool of 10 processes in each python process.

```
songs_pool = Pool()
songs_pool =Pool(processes=10)
return_pool = songs_pool.map(getVideo,songs_list)
```

I get some client errors when the value of m is increased to more than 2 and the pool is increased to >5. I get forbidden errors. When I check the number of requests in the google analytics,it shows that the number of requests are 250 per sec. But according to the documentation the limit is 3000 requests per sec. I dont understand why am I getting the client errors. Can you tell me if there is a way to not get this errors and run the program quicker.

if m = 2 and process = 10 , i get no errors but it takes so much time to complete.
But if I increase them , then I get client errors which are ~ 5% of the total requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The per-user-limit is 3000 requests per second from a single IP address, and as soon as you go above that in a given second you'll start getting the forbidden errors. The analytics you see in the developers console will only report your average number of requests over a 5 minute period; therefore, if you had zero requests for 4 minutes, then started running your routine, the console may show only 250 requests per second (as an average) but your app likely is overrunning the limit in a given period of time or two.

It seems that you're handling it in the best way possible if speed is your concern; you'll want to run it fast enough to get a very small number of errors (so you know you're staying up there at your limit). Another option, though, might be to look into using etags; if you find yourself requesting info on the same videos a lot, you can let etags tell you whether or not any info has changed (and if the API responds that nothing has changed, it doesn't count against either your quota or your reqests/sec.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try using etags and see if it reduces the errors.